# Durandal showMessage don't recognize break line

Tags: javascript, html, durandal

I'm trying using Durandal to show a message, but I can't get how to break line, so I'm getting all my info in one line.
Anybody can help with that?

HTML

```
if(bid.exposed){
     var msg = 'Bidder details : ' +
        "\n" + 'Business Name : '+ bid.businessName +
        "\n" + 'Username' : ' + bid.fullName;
     app.showMessage(msg, Expose, 'Confirm');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `/n` to `<br/>` as you are dealing with html when you show the message.

```
if(bid.exposed){
     var msg = 'Bidder details : ' +
        "<br/>" + 'Business Name : '+ bid.businessName +
        "<br/>" + 'Username' : ' + bid.fullName;
     app.showMessage(msg, Expose, 'Confirm');
}
```

**EDIT**

Looking deeper at the code, the file `scripts/durandal/dialog.js` contains the code for the dialog box.

This is the code that generates the HTML for the dialog.

```
  MessageBox.defaultViewMarkup = [
        '<div data-view="plugins/messageBox" class="messageBox">',
            '<div class="modal-header">',
                '<h3 data-bind="text: title"></h3>',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="modal-body">',
                '<p class="message" data-bind="text: message"></p>',
            '</div>',
            '<div class="modal-footer" data-bind="foreach: options">',
                '<button class="btn" data-bind="click: function () { $parent.selectOption($data); }, text: $data, css: { \'btn-primary\': $index() == 0, autofocus: $index() == 0 }"></button>',
            '</div>',
        '</div>'
    ].join('\n');
```

The issue with how we were both trying to display the details is on the line

```
'<p class="message" data-bind="text: message"></p>',
```

According to the [knockout.js Documentation on text binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html), it will not render html elements.

There are a couple of options.

1. Create a [Custom HTML Dialog template and a Custom Dialog js file](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Showing-Message-Boxes-And-Modals.html).
2. Modify the Durandal dialog.js file (quick and easy to get you out of a tight spot but not recommended)

I think that the best course of action would be to create your own Dialog Template to display the information laid out how you want it.  There are samples on how to do this in the [(dfiddle) durandal samples.](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#modal)
[Durandal Sample ZIP file](http://durandaljs.com/version/2_0_0/HTML%20Samples.zip)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my version of dialog.js, which I have requested to be pulled to the 2.1.0 branch, which is still under work. You can find my version of dialog.js at the following location:

https://github.com/TommiGustafsson/Durandal/blob/master/src/plugins/js/dialog.js

In that version, I have changed the text binding to html binding among many other improvements. Then, you can use <br /> tag or any other html in your message box. If you want to know about other improvements I have made, you can read about them in the following post:

https://github.com/BlueSpire/Durandal/pull/362